# How to test a method which is passed to a directive controller

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a method which is defined in a controller. This method is passed to a custom directive which has an isolated scope. How do I test the implementation of `$scope.search` correctly?

#### AutocompleteCtrl

```
$scope.query = function (term) {
    // some async stuff
};
```

#### Template

```
<div ng-controller="AutocompleteCtrl">
    <div typeahead data-search="query(term)"></div>
</div>
```

#### Directive (excerpt)

```
return {
    controller: 'AutocompleteDirectiveCtrl',
    scope: {
        search: '&'
    }
}
```

#### AutocompleteDirectiveCtrl

```
$scope.query = function (term) {
    if (term.length > ($scope.minChars - 1)) {
        $scope.search({term: term});
    }
};
```

#### Unit-test

```
describe('Autocomplete AutocompleteDirectiveCtrl', function () {
    var $scope, $window;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
        $window = {
            location: {},
            document: window.document
        };

        // We register our new $window instead of the old
        $provide.constant('$window', $window);
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller('AutocompleteDirectiveCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
    }));


    describe('Ducktyping', function () {
        it('should contain a submit method', function () {
            expect($scope.submit).toBeDefined();
        });
    });

    describe('Controller Functionality', function () {
        it('should return false if a submit request has no term set', function () {
            expect($scope.submit()).toEqual(false);
        });
        it('should redirect to search-results page if a term is present', function () {
            $scope.action = 'search-results.html';
            $scope.submit('mySearchTerm');
            expect($window.location.href).toBe('search-results.html/products/mySearchTerm');
        });
        it('should do a searchquery if term length is equal or longer then min-chars', function () {
            $scope.minChars = 3;
            $scope.query('myTerm');
        });
    });
});
```

###Log

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$scope.search({term: term})')
```

Comment: Could you add the test's beforeEach function? I'm not able to tell if you're initializing the controller and the directive correctly.

Comment: I've updated my questions with the complete test suite.

Comment: You should test the $scope.query method on the unit tests for AutocompleteCtrl. You shouldn't care if you are using it in a directive or child controller, it should be tested where it was created.

Comment: But the logic in `$scope.query`(AutocompleteCtrl) is different from `$scope.query` (AutocompleteDirectiveCtrl). It is my fault to use equal names. The first method is responsible for fetching data from the server. The second one does a new request (with updated search term) to the server.

Comment: I would start by adding a couple of `debugger` statements inside the AutocompleteDirectiveCtrl to test if the $scope.query method is being correctly defined when calling the $controller service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was an easy one. I had only to mock a required method.

```
it('should do a searchquery if term length is equal or bigger then min-chars', function () {
    $scope.minChars = 3;
    $scope.search = function (term) {
        return term;
    };
    spyOn($scope, 'search');
    $scope.query('bes');
    expect($scope.search).toHaveBeenCalledWith({term: 'bes'});
});
```